# how to get anchor tag from textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text area which contain list of link in textarea and their inside content for e.g.

```
<p>For example <a href="http://example1.com"> section 1</a></p>
<p class="str-txt">See <b><a href="http://www.example2.com">stryker.com</a>.</b> Follow Investors > Financial information for financial statements.</p>
```

Above information is given inside a text area. I want after click submit I want to retrieve all anchor tag's. for e.g. I want output like

```
example1.com
example2.com
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Below I have placed my coding for your reference.

Comment: <div id="textarea">
<textarea id="message" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="button">
<input id="url" type="button" value="URL Link Extraction"></input>
<input type="button" value="Internal Link Extraction"></input>
<input type="button" value="Validation"></input>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>


$(document).ready(function()
{
$("input#url").click(function()
{
var messagea = $("#message").val();
var href = $(messagea).filter("a[href*='http://']");
$("<br>").appendTo(href);
$("#result").html(href);
});
});

Comment: Please click the edit link under the question to add the code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uncwfe35/8/)

I modified your code(mainly JS). find your answer below. also check the JsFiddle Demo.

### HTML

```
<div id="textarea"> <textarea id="message" rows="10" cols="60">    
</textarea> </div> 

<div id="button"> <input id="url" type="button" value="URL Link Extraction"></input> <input type="button" value="Internal Link Extraction"></input> <input type="button" value="Validation"></input> </div> 

<div id="result"> </div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("input#url").click(function() { 
        var messagea = $("#message").val();
        var messageaHtml = $('<div></div>').html(messagea);
        var linkifiedText = linkify(messageaHtml.text());
        linkifiedText = $('<div></div>').html(linkifiedText);
        var links = linkifiedText.find("a[href]");
        links = links.add(messageaHtml.find("a[href]"));
        links.each(function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if(isUrl(link))
           $("#result").append(link+'<br/>'); 
        });
    }); 
});


 function isUrl(s) {
var regexp = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$/i;
return regexp.test(s);
}

 function linkify(html) {
  return html.replace(/[^\"]http(.*)\.([a-zA-Z]*)/g, ' <a href="http$1.$2">http$1.$2</a>');
}
```

### Test case: Enter following HTML in textarea and click link extraction button

```
<p>http://www.linkedin.com</p>
<div>http://www.twitter.com</div>
<p><a href="http://google.net" />Google</a></p>
<a href="http://www.google.com" />Google</a>
<a href="http://google.net" />Google</a>
<a href="www.google.com" />Google</a>
<a href="http://www.google.org" />Google</a>
<a href="http://www.google.cc" />Google</a>
<a href="http://google.in" />Google</a>
<a href="http://google.edu" />Google</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am forget to tick.